# sbt assembly akka-stream_2.12:2.4.19 and akka-actor_2.12:2.4.19 are evicted

Tags: jar, sbt, akka, akka-stream, sbt-assembly

I want to make fat jar of my project with sbt assembly. Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "projName"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.3",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.8",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.8.6",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.2.1",
  "org.knowm.xchange" % "xchange-core" % "4.2.0",
  "org.knowm.xchange" % "xchange-btce" % "4.2.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

After running

```
sbt assembly
```

i got such warning:

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.4.19 -> 2.5.3
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.4.19 -> 2.5.3
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

Then i run `sbt evicted` for more detail and here what i got:

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.4.19 -> 2.5.3 (caller: com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:10.0.8, default:btceclient_2.12:1.0)
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.4.19 -> 2.5.3 (caller: com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5.3, com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:10.0.8, default:btceclient_2.12:1.0)
[info] Here are other libraries that were evicted:
[info]  * com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.2 -> 2.8.6 (caller: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:2.8.6, com.github.mmazi:rescu:1.9.0, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.8.6)
[info]  * com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 -> 2.8.6 (caller: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6, com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:2.8.6)
[info]  * com.typesafe:config:1.2.0 -> 1.3.1 (caller: com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.12:0.2.1, default:btceclient_2.12:1.0, com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.5.3)
```

I know what are eviction warnings but i don't know how to solve that in current situation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore this message because 2.4 and 2.5 versions [are binary compatible](http://akka.io/blog/news/2017/04/13/akka-2.5.0-released), so it is okay to upgrade from 2.4 to 2.5.

Comment: when i run fat jar i got exception about missing akka.version parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Modified merge strategy:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

Here you can see new line: `case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat` .
I think it is needless to explain what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

The eviction message is clear. A quick [search](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe.akka%7Cakka-http-core_2.12%7C10.0.8%7Cjar) in maven for `akka-http_2.12 : 10.0.8` will show you that this artifact depends of `akka-stream_2.12:2.4.19`.
One solution, you could downgrade `akka-actor` and `akka-stream` to 2.4.19 in the dependencies setting.